# use Htmlunit, doesn't work button click();

Tags: java, javascript, authentication, htmlunit

Hi all :) I'm new in HtmlUnit (Java). It's my first time to use HtmlUnit stuffs.
I'm having some issues to log-in to a web page.

And some part of the source of the web site is below.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="AlignRight">
                    <div class="Button" id="loginButton">
                        <div class="Left">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="Middle"><a href="javascript:submitForm(document.getElementById('localLogin'), 'submit');"><strong>log-in</strong></a></div>
                        <div class="Right">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And the some part of the code that i worte is below and plus i set "webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);" already.

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://************");
            HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("login");
        HtmlElement button = form.getElementById("loginButton");

                    // Enter login and passwd
                    form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute("******");
                    form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("******");
                    page = (HtmlPage) button.click();
                            System.out.println(page.getUrl());
                    System.out.println("Success");
```

so.. after running the code, The url should be changed as after clicking the button, but I couldn't see any difference. There's no error for running but just i can't see the changed Url..

Is there anything wrong ? .. 
Please give me some advice  T_T ! Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

You may try to execute the javascript manually:

```
   page.executeJavaScript("javascript:submitForm(document.getElementById('localLogin'), 'submit');");
```

Comment: Btw, are you sure the url will change after form submission?